# In App search in Android

Tags: android

I have searched a lot regarding In App search in android, What i ended up http://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing/index.html
https://developers.google.com/app-indexing/
and few application on Play store like Andro search. But what I am looking for is precise search in internal application installed on my phone. Say, there is linkedIn, some News app, or any image editor app, or dropbox then the search should be able to fetch the result from inside these apps. 
Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it might be useful to search for the application you want from Google. Google also shows the applications on the phone.

Answer (score 0):

I'm in the same quest? Looks like Android don't have anymore this feature, I can't find this feature on the new released Android 10. Only the Samsung Galaxy seems to have this feature in the world of Androids, this is very sad.